# How to add correct door in the layout

Tags: modeling

As a new entrant to this group and Blender, I am facing many problems. The interface is very well understandable and seems easy, but while actually working on it some error occur:

1. When I add Door in any of the layouts it comes in three asymmetrical parts, which is very difficult to add/boolean in the layout.
2. When I want to move or resize the object only the outer layer/boundaries of the selected object is moved until I click right and select shade flat.

[image]
[image]

Comment: "When I add Door"- how do you add a door? "the layouts" - what layouts? "it comes"- where does it come from? "which is very difficult to add/boolean in the layout" - What do you mean by that? "only the outer layer/boundaries of the selected object is moved until I click right and select shade flat" - what are you talking about? What are you trying to do and how and what exactly happens?

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other one separately. Thanks